# Javascript:how to make setTimeout not delay for the first execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I built an instant search function which is similar to google search. A setTimeout function was used to debounce/throttle the search. However, I don't want the delay for the first execution of searchq()function. How do I modify the code to achieve this?

```
var timeout = null;

function doDelayedSearch(txt) {

          if (timeout) {  
            clearTimeout(timeout);
          }

            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                searchq(txt); //this is the search function (posting and fetching result)
                }, 1000);
}

function searchq(txt){
        // get the value
            // txt = $("input").val();
            // post the value
            if(txt){
                $.post("search.php", {searchVal: txt}, function(result){
                    $("#search_output").html(result+"<br><a class='anchor_tag_s' href='createobject.php?object="+txt+"'><div id='notfound'>Not found above? Create Here.</div><a>");
                });
            }
            else{
                $("#search_output").html("");
            }
        };
```

Comment: As an aside, note that you don't need the `if (timeout)`, you can just call `clearTimeout()` directly. Your if condition will be true *every* time `doDelayedSearch()` is called, except the first time, because `timeout` never gets set back to a falsey value. There's no harm in calling `clearTimeout()` with a null value or with the id of an already completed or cancelled timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

<s>just call the function after setting the timeout</s>
EDIT: call the function when there is no timeout yet

```
function doDelayedSearch(txt) {

          if (!timeout) {
            searchq(txt); // the first time is the only time, there is no timeout
          }
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                searchq(txt); //this is the search function (posting and fetching result)
                }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: But then it'll always be called twice for each call to `doDelayedSearch()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn had the right clue: _Your if condition will be true every time ... except the first time_

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
function doDelayedSearch(txt) {
    clearTimeout(timeout); // clearTimeout(null) will not throw.
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        searchq(txt);
    }, timeout ? 1000 : 0); // if timeout is null, then call with minimum delay, otherwise one second. 
}
```

This way, `searchq()` is always called from a `setTimeout()` but with special case for the first call when `timeout` is still null.

Answer (score 0):

You could cheat and set a global variable.

```
global.firstExecution = true;

if (global.firstExecution == true) {
    searchq(txt);
}
else {
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        searchq(txt); //this is the search function (posting and fetching result)
    }, 1000);
}
```

In your function then say:

```
global.firstExecution = false;
```

It isn't a glamorous solution, but it will work.